# maximum level of subdivisions of OpenCL Kernels

Tags: opencl

I have a question for my understanding in general. For this question I build up a scenario to keep it as simple as possible.

**Lets say:**
I have a structure of 2 variables (*x* and *y*). And also I have thousands of objects of this structure in a buffer next to each other in an array. The initial values of these structure are different. But later always the same arithmetic operations should be applied to each of these structures. (So this is extremely good for the GPU because each worker is doing exactly the same operation only with different values without branching.) Additionally this structs are not needed on CPU at all. So only at the entire end of the program all values should be stored back to the CPU.

The operations on these structs are limited as well! Lets say, we have 8 operations which can be applied:

1. x + y, store result in x
2. x + y, store result in y
3. x + x, store result in x
4. y + y, store result in y
5. x * y, store result in x
6. x * y, store result in y
7. x * x, store result in x
8. y * y, store result in y

when creating one kernel program for one operation, the kernel program for operation 1 would look like the following:

```
__kernel void operation1(__global float *structArray) 
{

    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0) * 2;

    // Do the operation
    structArray[i] = structArray[i] + structArray[i + 1]; //this line will change for different operations (+, *, store to x, y)
}
```

when executing these kernels multiple times in some order like: operation 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 7, 3, 5....
Then I have for each execution at least one global memory read operation and also one global memory write operation. But in Theory if each worker would store its structure (x and y value) in the private memory the execution would be faster by a factor of like 50 or so.

**Is it possible to do something like this?:**

```
__private float x;
__private float y;

__kernel void operation1(void) 
{       
    // Do the operation
    x = x + y; //this line will change for different operations (+, *, store to x, y)
}
```

to do so, you fist need to store the values... for example like the following:

```
__private float x;
__private float y;

__kernel void operationStore(__global float *structArray) 
{       
    int i = get_global_id(0) * 2;
    //store the x and y value from global to private memory
    x = structArray[i];
    y = structArray[i + 1];
}
```

and of cause at the entire end of the program you need to store them back to global memory to later push it to the CPU again:

```
__private float x;
__private float y;

__kernel void operationStoreToGlobal(__global float *structArray) 
{       
    int i = get_global_id(0) * 2;
    //store the x and y value from private to global memory
    structArray[i] = x;
    structArray[i + 1] = y;
}
```

**So my question:**

1. Can I somehow manage to store values on private or maybe local memory during different kernel calls? If so, I would only have the performance reduction by the program queue.
2. How many clock cycles does the program queue need to change from one kernel to another?
3. Is this timing of the change of kernel, kernel size specific? If so: Does is depend on number of operations within the kernel or does is depend on number of buffer bindings (rebind stuff)
4. Is there a thumb of rule, how mush operations (counted by clock cycles) a kernel should at least have to be performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is not possible. You cannot communicate data across kernels in "global variables" in `private` or `local` memory space. You need to use `global` kernel arguments to temporarily store results, and thus write the values to video memory temporarily and read from video memory in the next kernel.
   The only memory space allowed for "global variables" is `constant`: With it, you can create large look-up tables for example. These are read-only. `constant` variables are cached in L2 whenever possible.
2. Potentially several thousand. When you finish one kernel and start another, you have a global synchronization point. All instances of kernel 1 need to be finished before kernel 2 can start.
3. Yes. It depends on the global range, local (work group) range, number of operations (especially `if-else` branching, because one work group can take significantly longer than the other), but not on the number of kernel arguments / buffer bindings. The larger the global size, the longer the kernel takes, the smaller are relative time-vatiations between work groups and the smaller is the relative performance loss of the kernel change (synchronization point).
4. Better question: How large should the global range be for a kernel to be performant? Answer: Very large, like 100 times the CUDA core / stream processor count.

There are tricks to reduce the number of required global synchronization points. For example: If a kernel can combine multiple different tasks from different kernels, squash two kernels together into one.
Example here: lattice Boltzmann method, two-step swap versus one-step swap.

Another common trick is to allocate a buffer twice in video memory. In even steps, read from A and write to B and in odd steps the other way around. Avoid reading from A and at the same time writing to other elements of A (introduces race-conditions).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a question to no. 3: what is the global and local range? Is the local range the number of workers in a work-group? and the global range the numbers of work-groups? Why should branching effect time difference in loading a kernel? The question was addressed to asking at the time from a finished kernel (when all workers are finished) to load a new kernel. Does it here make a difference? Thanks!

Comment: Global range is the total number of work items, local range is the number of work items within a work group. Global range must be a multiple of the local range. Local range must be some multiple of 32. All threads within a work group need to execute the same branch, so if two work groups compute different branches of signigicantly different length, the kernel has to wait for the slowest work group to finish, elongating kernel runtime. If some threads within a work group do branch A and some branch B, the work group has to execute both branches. The time gap between kernels is not affected.